# BigQuery: Possible two merge 2 arrays of ranges where you split the range if they overlap

Tags: google-bigquery

I was wondering if the following case is possible within BigQuery.
There are 2 tables of intervals. The intervals in a single table do not overlap with other intervals in the same table. The intervals however can overlap with intervals in the other table.

I want to merge the intervals, but also divide the intervals into multiple intervals if they overlap. So if for example the interval is in table A from 5/8/2020 - 5/9/2020 and there is an interval in B 18/8/2020 - 1/9/2020, then I want to split the interval as 5/8/2020 - 18/8/2020 (in A), 18/8/2020 - 1/9/2020 (in A and B) and 1/9/2020 - 5/9/2020 (in A).

A more extensive example: We have a table with intervals where people eat Apples

| ID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/19 | 01/04/19 |
| 2 | 01/01/19 | 03/01/19 |

And a table with intervals where people eat Bananas

| ID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15/12/18 | 12/01/19 |
| 1 | 01/02/19 | 17/02/19 |
| 1 | 15/03/19 | 15/04/19 |
| 2 | 01/06/19 | 01/07/19 |

And now we want to combine those intervals and classify the intervals as either, apple eaters, banana eaters, or apple and banana eaters.

| ID | StartDate | EndDate | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15/12/18 | 01/01/19 | B |
| 1 | 01/01/19 | 12/01/19 | AB |
| 1 | 12/01/19 | 01/02/19 | A |
| 1 | 01/02/19 | 17/02/19 | AB |
| 1 | 17/02/19 | 15/03/19 | A |
| 1 | 15/03/19 | 01/04/19 | AB |
| 1 | 01/04/19 | 15/04/19 | B |
| 2 | 01/01/19 | 03/01/19 | A |
| 2 | 01/06/19 | 01/07/19 | B |

Is it possible to solve this with bigQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below query :

```sql
WITH stacked AS (
  SELECT ID, date, STRING_AGG(type, '' ORDER BY type) type FROM (
    SELECT *, 'A' type FROM Apples
     UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'B' type FROM Bananas
  ), UNNEST (GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%y', StartDate), PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%y', EndDate), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) date
   GROUP BY 1, 2
),
partitioned AS (
  SELECT ID, date, type,
         COUNTIF(flag) OVER w AS div,
         type = 'AB' AND LEAD(type) OVER w <>'AB' in_AB,
         type <> 'AB' AND LAG(type) OVER w = 'AB' out_AB,
         type <> 'AB' AND LEAD(type, 1, 'A') OVER w <> 'AB' bw_AB,
    FROM (
      SELECT ID, date, type, type <> LAG(type) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) AS flag 
        FROM stacked
    )
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date)
)
SELECT ID,
       MIN(IF(out_AB, date - 1, date)) StartDate,
       MAX(IF(in_AB or bw_AB, date, date + 1)) EndDate,
       ANY_VALUE(type) type
  FROM partitioned
 GROUP BY ID, div
 ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

[image]

With sample tables:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE Apples AS
select 1 ID, '01/01/19' StartDate, '01/04/19'EndDate union all
select 2, '01/01/19', '03/01/19';

CREATE TEMP TABLE Bananas AS
select 1 ID, '15/12/18' StartDate, '12/01/19' EndDate union all
select 1, '01/02/19', '17/02/19' union all
select 1, '15/03/19', '15/04/19' union all
select 2, '01/06/19', '01/07/19';
```